# Get the id of the last saved entry

Tags: php, database, laravel, last-insert-id

Save gives only true or false.

```
$query = (new Item())->fill([
    'first'=>$first,
    'second'=>$second
])->save();
$lastInsertId = $query->id;
//does not work...
return ['status'=>true];
```

Comment: Please translate your question to English, so we can help you (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `create`function instead.

```
$item = Item::create([
    'first' => $first,
    'second' => $second
]);

$id = $item->id;
```